# Как отслеживать KeyEvent в JavaFX и SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

JavaFX, SceneBuilder.
Если добавить код ниже в `start()` - все работает.

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getCode()) {
            case W -> {
                System.out.println("w");
            }
            case A -> System.out.println("a");
            case S -> System.out.println("s");
            case D -> System.out.println("d");
        }
    }
});
```

Но полагаю подобный код должен находиться все таки в котроллере. Но в контроллере он не реагирует на него.

```
@FXML
void KeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("qwe");
}
@FXML
void MouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("asd");
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    bdPane.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });
}
```

1. Если указать функцию `KeyPressed` в `SceneBuilder` - ничего не происходит. Притом, если добавить `MouseClicked` - все работает отлично. Метки в *fxml* добавлены. Пробовал разные варианты - на `borderPane/gridPane`
2. Попытался через интерфейс `Initializable` - сама функция отрабатывает, но код `handle` - нет.

Правильно ли понимаю - вешать `KeyEvent` на НЕ изменяемые объекты нельзя? Спорное утверждение, т.к. если нарисовать скажем прямоугольник, к нему указать функцию, которая, например, должна его передвигать по нажатиям с клавиатуры, тоже ничего не происходит.

Как вешать обработки событий клавиатуры, если мне не надо что-то вводить, а просто реализовать какую-то логику в программе?

Comment: Описание метода: "Defines a function to be called when this Node or its child Node has input focus and a key has been pressed. The function is called only if the event hasn't been already consumed during its capturing or bubbling phase.", см.[onKeyPressed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyPressedProperty), т.е. обработчик срабатывает когда сам узел или один из дочерних узлов получает фокус ввода и в нем нажимается кнопка. Пустая панель не может получить фокус ввода, поэтому работать будет, если добавить например, текстовое поле.

Comment: Ну, хотя в Scene про такой метод похожий текст написан (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#onKeyPressedProperty), но со Scene почему-то работает. В общем, похоже что придется делать именно через scene.

Comment: * точнее если добавить текстовое поле, то будет работать onKeyReleased и onKeyTyped. С onKeyPressed не работает, скорее всего из-за того, что текстовое поле поглощает (consumes) это событие и не транслирует родительским узлам.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    rect.focusTraversableProperty().set(true);
    rect.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case W -> System.out.println("w");
                case A -> System.out.println("a");
                case S -> System.out.println("s");
                case D -> System.out.println("d");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

focusTraversableProperty() - устанавливает должен ли узел находится в цикле обхода фокуса. После этого все отрабатывает отлично.

Insolor - спасибо за подсказку Ж)

Comment: А rect у вас какой объект? Я попробовал просто с GridPane - не срабатывает.

Comment: rect - прямоугольник добавленный через SceneeBuilder. По структуре fxml - внешний BorderPane, вложенный в него GridPane, и в ячейку добавлен прямогольник. на внешний Border Pane не срабатывает.