# Подскажите как реализовать обработчик событий клавиатуры в JavaFX непосредственно через контроллер

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите как реализовать обработчик событий клавиатуры в JavaFX непосредственно через контроллер.
Я видел множество способов, но все они непосредственно через main класс, а мне нужно через контроллер.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отслеживать KeyEvent в JavaFX и SceneBuilder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248003/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-keyevent-%d0%b2-javafx-%d0%b8-scenebuilder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно вызвать объект класса model и соответствующий метод в классе контроллер.

```
    private final Model model = new Model()
    private void go() {
    model.setButton(send_Button);
    model.setTextArea(output_text);
    model.setTextField(write_text);
    model.send();
}


public void send(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    this.go();
}
```

А вот в методе send можете уже делать так как видели в main